# Simple module to view article title and one image from within article,

Tags: php, module, joomla, joomla-article

I need to created simple module to view article title and one image from the article, The problem is I have no idea how to get one image from the article.

**This is my code:**

```
<?php
  defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "
  SELECT ".$db->nameQuote('images')." ,".$db->nameQuote('title')."  
    FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__content').";
  ";

  $db->setQuery($query);
  $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
  foreach ($rows as $row)
  {
     //echo "<p>The article text of '$row->fulltext' is $row->id </p>\n";
       echo "<p>The article image of '$row->images' </p>\n";
       echo "<p>The article title of '$row->title' </p>\n";

  }
  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Joomla articles do not have a field for storing image date. Images are inserted directly in to the introtext or fulltext fields. You would need to use a regular expression to find the first instance of an image in order to do this.

The other option is to install one of many CCK type extensions that allow you to define content types or add extra fields to the Joomla article. K2 does exactly what you are trying to do with the default installation including the module to display the title and image.